# How to use process.env variables in browser running by Cypress

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, cypress

In the source code of my application (React based on create-react-app) I'm using env variables like so: `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` which are stored in my `.env.*` files.

But when I run the same application under the Cypress the `process.env` object is empty. How can I provide these variables to be used in React application when it's running under Cypress?

I know that I have a possibility to set Cypress env variables but it is not what I want - this is a different scope.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [configuration API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api.html) and do something like this on your plugins file. Set `config.env = process.env` which will set your entire node env for `Cypress`.

```
// cypress/plugins/index.js
module.exports = (on, config) => {

  // modify env value
  config.env = process.env

  // return config
  return config
}
```

You can also selectively assign the values that you want with `config.env.YOUR_VAR = process.env.YOUR_VAR`.

Comment: The op is asking how to set `process.env` variables in Cypress.  This answer says how to use `process.env` variables to set Cypress environment variables, no?  What am I missing?

Comment: You need first install `dotenv` and import it `require("dotenv").config();` on the top of the `cypress/plugins/index.js` file

Comment: I don't get why this answer is accepted, it doesn't seem right and doesn't work in Next.js. Process.env is not set client-side (Next bundler will inline this value but in Cypress we must manually define a value for "window.process.env")

Answer (score 20):

## Updated in Cypress version 10.3.0 and above

In Cypress, environment variables (accessible via `Cypress.env`) doesn't share the same scope as OS-level environment variables. In order to make `process.env` variables available in `Cypress`, you should use a third party library, such as [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv/v/8.2.0) package, which is very popular.

```
npm install dotenv
```

Make sure this line of code sitting on top of your `cypress.config.js`

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Now you're good to go using process.env, but only under that `cypress.config.js` file. As mentioned in another answer, you should leverage the [Cypress.env()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env) command by passing all `process.env` properties to Cypress environment variables, so that you can access those variables globally in Cypress

```
// cypress.config.js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = {
        ...process.env,
        ...config.env
      }
      return config 
    }
  }
})
```

Note that in Cypress version `10.0.0` and above, [setupNodeEvents](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#setupNodeEvents) was added to replace the deprecated plugins file.

Now you can retrieve those variables by:

```
Cypress.env("your_proccess_env_property")
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally set .env files. I used below code.
```import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
const envFilename = process.env.ENV_FILENAME || ''
dotenv.config({path: path.resolve(__dirname, `config/${envFilename}.env`)});```

Answer (score 3):

For my use case, I was simply able to do the following.

```js
// cypress.config.js
require('dotenv').config();
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = defineConfig({
    ...,
    env: {
        ...process.env,
    },
});
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Create `cypress.env.json` file that contains your environment variables:

```json
{
  "api_url": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

Then set `process.env` in your `cypress/support/index.js`:

```js
...

before(() => {
  process.env. REACT_APP_API_URL = Cypress.env("api_url");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same variables, the same way as react app, while running only Cypress without an app (this is the reason why process.env is empty). You could add this in `cypress.config.js`

```
const dotenvOutput = require('dotenv').config()
```

then access the variables as

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {
    env: {
       api_url: dotenvOutput.parsed.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    },
```

You also need to make sure that the `.env` file is available where the cypress is ran.

Answer (score 0):

New, Better Answer (2023)

Cypress config options will be overwritten by OS level env variables if they follow the `CYPRESS_` naming convention, per the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_).  This also applies to env vars set on the command line or 'in your CI provider'.

For example,

```
e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'localhost',
}
```

will be overwritten by OS env var with name `CYPRESS_BASE_URL`.

This is the way.