# process.env empty object in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, cypress, dotenv

I am working on a React app bootstraped from create-react-app few years ago.

The app has a `.env.dev` file with many variables.
The start script is `"start": "env-cmd -f .env.dev --use-shell \"react-scripts start\"",`

React script version: `"react-scripts": "^4.0.1",`

When I `console.log("gggg", process.env);` I get all the variables.
When I:

```
describe('Login via API', () => {
  it('Test login', () => {
    console.log('teeest', process.env)
    cy.login()
  })
})
```

instead I get an empty object.

I tried to read the question [How to use process.env variables in browser running by Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818181/how-to-use-process-env-variables-in-browser-running-by-cypress)

however this question does not answer my question on how to make the process.env variables available to Cypress test files.

Also this question says to install `dotenv`. Dotenv comes with react-scripts, so no need to install it if the app was create by create-react-app.

I also tried this:
in `cypress.config.js` I added:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = process.env
      return config
    }
  }
})
```

And in the spec I try to get the variable defined in `.env.dev` file:

```
  it('Test login', () => {
    console.log('new', Cypress.env('REACT_APP_USERNAME'))
    cy.login()
  })
```

Still getting `undefined`.

Can anyone please help me to understand what's wrong? How can I make it work?

Edit:
According to an answer here I tried to install dotenv:

1. `npm install dotenv --save`
2. imported in the test:

   import 'dotenv/config'

   describe('Login via API', () => {
   it('Test login', () => {
   console.log('newwwww', Cypress.env('REACT_APP_USERNAME'))
   console.log('teeest', process.env)
   cy.login()
   })
   })
3. `Npm start`
4. `npm run cypress:open`

Result:

```
newwwww undefined
login-test.cy.js:7 teeest {}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use process.env variables in browser running by Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818181/how-to-use-process-env-variables-in-browser-running-by-cypress)

Comment: @agoff unfortunately not, I updated the original question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `"start": "env-cmd -f .env.dev --use-shell \"react-scripts start\""`, the `env-cmd` command is specific to the process for the react app.

You would need the same to run before cypress opens it's process

#### package.json

```js
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cy:open": "env-cmd  -f .env.dev cypress open",
    ...
  }
}
```

---

#### Avoiding conflict with other env setting

I also recommend using the **spread operator** as shown below, otherwise you would lose any env var added in other ways, e.g command line additions.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = {
        ...process.env,                 // add all process env var here
        ...config.env                   // plus any command line overrides
      }
      return config                     // return the altered config
    },
  },
  env: {
    login_url: '/login',                // define some specific env var here
    products_url: '/products'
  }
});
```

---

#### Avoiding pollution of Cypress settings

If you take a look at `Settings/Project Settings` in the Cypress runner, you'll see a huge number of unnecessary settings which come from the general machine env var.

To pick just those with prefix `REACT_`,

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

      const reactEnv = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((obj, key) => {
        if (key.startsWith('REACT_')) {
          obj[key] = process.env[key];
        }
        return obj;
      }, {});

      config.env = {
        ...reactEnv,                    // add REACT_ process env var here
        ...config.env                   // plus any command line overrides
      }
      return config                     // return the altered config
    },
  },
  env: {
    login_url: '/login',                // define some specific env var here
    products_url: '/products'
  }
});
```

Comment: `env-cmd` is not defined (Linux).

Comment: Some commands are not native to your operating system. In this case you will have to use `npm` to install env-cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about dotenv being included with react-scripts, but to access it in your test files you'll have to explicitly import it.

```
npm install dotenv
```

then at the top of your cypress code

```
import 'dotenv/config'
```

See usage instructions here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately still undefined. I updated the the questin with "Edit"

Comment: Have you tried putting these variables into .env instead of .env.dev?

Comment: Just tried. Unfortunately the same