# How does Cypress read the Windows environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, cypress

I have set my environment variables in 'Cypress.env.json' file.

While running the cypress test, it reads the Cypress.env variables successfully.

But to be more secure, rather than 'hard-cording' the values, my team asked me to keep these variables as separate 'parameters' which are read from Windows 10 Environment variables.

How do I achieve this ?

I need to set an environment variable in Windows level.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer [How to use process.env variables in browser running by Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72991511/16997707) - essentially the `dotenv` package will read any variables you have set on the Windows environment. Also works for other OS like Linux.

The answer given is a bit naive for what you want to do, as there will be a lot of variables you do not need in the test.

This modification would be better

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const {defineConfig} = require('cypress')

require('dotenv').config()
const { secret1, secret2 } = process.env;   // extract two secret variables

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.env = {
        ...config.env,
        secret1,
        secret2,
      }
      return config 
    }
  }
})
```

Note the process.env values should come ***after*** the `config.env` values, so you are over-writing any defaults.

Those defaults would be in `cypress.env.json`, and stops the tests crashing if someone forgets to set their Windows environment values.

```js
{
  "host": "veronica.dev.local",
  "api_server": "http://localhost:8888/api/v1/",
  "secret1": "default-secret-value1",
  "secret2": "default-secret-value2",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set operating system environment variable that's name starts with **CYPRESS_** and it will be parsed and used in Cypress.
Example:

```
CYPRESS_HOST
```

will be available as

```
Cypress.env('HOST')
```