# How to handle `process.env` in client-side javascript files when running E2E tests in Cypress?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, cypress

Embarrassingly, this problem has been holding me up for days, and I must, must get on with my task for work, so I'm reaching out for help.

When running Cypress, I get said error: `process is not defined` and it points to a JavaScript file in the client portion of my project (shown below). I understand `process` is a nodeJS property, but I can obviously call this on the FE of my application, and must, so I don't understand why Cypress is throwing an error here. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm running node v14.x.x.

[image]

`vue.config.js`

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
// const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: '@import src/styles/base/entry.scss',
      },
    },
  },

  lintOnSave: false,

  publicPath: '/',

  transpileDependencies: true,
})
```

`Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/apm": "^5.27.1",
    "@sentry/browser": "^7.28.1",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^7.28.1",
    "auth0-js": "^9.20.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "axios-retry": "^3.3.1",
    "big.js": "^6.2.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.40",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.16.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}
```

Cypress webpack config

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
// ***********************************************************
// This example plugins/index.js can be used to load plugins
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off loading
// the plugins file with the 'pluginsFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/plugins-guide
// ***********************************************************

// This function is called when a project is opened or re-opened (e.g. due to
// the project's config changing)
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const webpackPreprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
  const defaults = webpackPreprocessor.defaultOptions
  // Add to existing rules
  defaults.webpackOptions.module.rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.sass$/i,
      use: [
        // creates 'style' nodes from JS strings
        "vue-style-loader",
        // Translates CSS into CommonJS
        "css-loader",
        // Compiles Sass to CSS
        {
          loader: "sass-loader",
          options: {
            additionalData: '@import src/styles/base/entry.scss',
            // sass-loader >= 8
            sassOptions: {
              indentedSyntax: true,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  )
  // Add first plugin
  defaults.webpackOptions.plugins = [ new VueLoaderPlugin() ]
  console.log(defaults)

  on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(defaults))
}
```

`sentryMixin.js`

```
...

const environment = process.env.VUE_APP_ENV
                    ^ this is where it points to the error
...
```

Comment: Does your site run locally without throwing an error? Usually a environment variable like this is evaluated at compile time, the fact that it’s trying to evaluate process suggests there’s an issue with compilation.

Comment: @Levidps Yes, it runs locally without a hitch.

Comment: I'm going to guess it works locally b/c you have the node server running locally and it's getting picked up some how. Considering the client doesn't have node running there's probably no `process` available to reference  on the client side. It's possible to use `process` for SSR code but if it's run on the browser it won't work and will error like this.

Comment: @Levidps So, maybe a dumb question -> must I configure Cypress via Webpack to run a BE like my local BE to serve a node.js server?

Comment: Not sure, I haven’t done much with cypress and nothing that involved `process.env` - this looks like a good [thread to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818181/how-to-use-process-env-variables-in-browser-running-by-cypress) with.